# Send one file at a time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import CameraID
import time
import os
image="/tmp/image/frame.png"

count = 1
while (count==1):

  # make sure file file exists, else show an error
  if ( not os.path.isfile(image)):
    print("Error: %s file not found" %image)
  else:
    print("Sending file %s ..." % image)
    print CameraID.run()
    print os.remove("/tmp/image/frame.png")
```

Does anybody know how to allow the file to be send one at a time with different filename. Once the file is send, it will be removed instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a list of files you want to transfer, then iterate over that list to send the files one by one.

Here a simple function to get the list of files:

```
def list_of_files(folder, extension):
    '''
    Return a list of file-paths for each file into a folder with the target extension.
    '''
    import glob
    return glob.glob(str(folder + '*.' + extension))
```

in your case it would be:

```
files = list_of_files('/tmp/image/','png')
for image in files:
    if ( not os.path.isfile(image)):
        print("Error: %s file not found" %image)
    else:
        print("Sending file %s ..." % image)
        print CameraID.run()
        print os.remove(image)
```

Without function definition:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('/tmp/image/*.png')

for image in files:
    if ( not os.path.isfile(image)):
        print("Error: %s file not found" %image)
    else:
        print("Sending file %s ..." % image)
        print CameraID.run()
        print os.remove(image)
```

Comment: Hi alec, I got the error that stated NameError : name list_of_files is not defined

Comment: Have you defined the function before running it?

Comment: I'm new to python, so i not sure what to do. What should i add in for the "Return a list of file-paths for each file into a folder with the target extension."?

Comment: You should just the first piece of code 'def list_...' before the second one! that's it. If you get 'list_of_files is not defined' it means that you have not ran the  'def list_...' before.

Comment: i use the method without function, but still shows me the error that the list_of_files is not defined

Comment: @Allen.Kan you are doing something very wrong then because in the code without function there is no call to list_of_file... are you sure you are running the right script? Did you save the code? If you are using jupyter notebook I suggest you to restart it.

Comment: Thanks, it is able to work but i have a error on my ftp side. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//tmp/image/*.png'

Comment: Try removing the first '/' from the path `files = glob.glob('tmp/image/*.png')`

Comment: When i put a while loop, it will not find the latest file and it will keep run and look the old file.

Comment: @Allen.Kan You need to break the loop then. For example, if the same file is processed again. You can contact me in private if you need some help. I cant help you without looking at your code. alec_djinn-at-yahoo-dot-com

Answer (score 0):

maybe can use list to save file, like: image=["/tmp/image/frame.png",""]
then use for x in image: